# How do I configure a date picker with third party js dependencies using Require JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, requirejs

I am attempting to use the following [Date Range Picker](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/#basics) in an application:
I was able to successfully get it working by placing the scripts in the `head` section of the page: However, I am not sure how to set this up using `Require JS`, and the third party dependencies.

For example: To use a `JQuery UI Date Picker` I simply do the following:

```
require.config({

    paths: {

        jquery: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery',
        'jquery-ui': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui'

    }

});
```

Then instantiate like this:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery-ui'], function ($) {

    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });

});
```

However, if there is an additional third party script, then I am not sure how to configure it:

Specifically, there is `moment.js` and `daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js` dependencies which I am struggling with.

Here is a complete [working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyeqokno/1/):

How do set this up using `Require JS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see if "amd" word is inside each lib. For example in [momentjs](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js) in 9th string you can see:

```
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
```

it means that you can include it in **path** part of requirejs config. But if you look inside the library and this word is not there then you should use [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) inside your config. For your case it will:

```
require.config({
    paths: {

        jquery: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery',
        'jquery-ui': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui'
        "momentjs":"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"
        //shim
        "daterangepicker":"//tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker"
    },
    shim:{
        "daterangepicker":{
            deps:["jquery-ui","momentjs"]
        }
    }
}
```

});

because daterangepicker has **jquery-ui** as dependency:

```
shim:{
        "daterangepicker":{
            deps:["jquery-ui","momentjs"]
        }
    }
```

and [jquery-ui](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js) depends on jquery at 10th string:

```
define(["jquery"], factory);
```

then you can include **only** "jquery-ui" as dependency for daterangepicker. So the result will be:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery',
        'jquery-ui': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui',
        momentjs: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment",
        //shim
        daterangepicker: "//tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-  daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker"
    },
    shim: {
        daterangepicker: {
            deps: ["jquery-ui", "momentjs"]
        }
    }
});

require(['jquery','daterangepicker','momentjs'], function    ($,dateRangePicker,momentjs) {
    //dateRangePicker will be undefined, but it's ok.
    window.moment = momentjs; //include momentjs in global scope because plugin wants it globally.
    $("#e2").daterangepicker({
        datepickerOptions: {
            numberOfMonths: 2
        }
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <script data-main="app.js" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js">  </script>
    <input id="e2"></input>
</body>
```

I did test of it and it works:

[image]

Comment: I can understand your English just fine and thank you so much for taking your time to help me understand this: I am still having issues. Now when the page loads the textbox simply retracts and the `ui` is missing. How ever the Calendar opens and closes when I click on this little dot. But the entire UI is gone.

Comment: Did you include: jquery-ui.min.css, bootstrap.css, jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css in <head> of document?

Comment: Yes, all of the files which are included in the JSFiffle posted above.

Comment: I found that "window.moment = undefined;" was bad idea, because plugin stop to work property, so delete this string. it helped?

Comment: Still the same issue. The text box stretches and then retracts into a little line.

Comment: unfortunately I do not see any other bugs in my code, the plugin is working properly, it may be some other libraries have an impact to you.

Comment: Okat, the problem is this: If I put the HTML below this code then it works:

Like this: `<script data-main="Scripts/main" src="Scripts/require.js" ></script>
<input id="e2" name="e2">`: I am not certain how this is going to work because it requires certain script in the `head` of the page.

Comment: Well, this is correct, I posted index.html in answer. Usually requirejs is called from the body and you shouldn't include scripts in <head>. All scripts  must be in requirejs.config.